# When creating a model instance how to fill ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want to create model instance like this:

```
new_tweet = Tweet.objects.create(text = tweet_object.text, date = tweet_object.date, username = tweet_object.username, retweet = tweet_object.retweet.all(), is_ret = True)
```

It's all going well until this: `retweet = tweet_object.retweet.all()`. It returns this error:  `'retweet' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

This is a ManyToMany field. So how to fill this field when creating new model instance?

By the way `tweet_object.retweet.all()` is consisted of many `retweet`objects.

EDIT:

Model:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    favourite = models.ManyToManyField(Favourite)
    retweet = models.ManyToManyField(Retweet)
    replies = models.ManyToManyField('Tweet')
    is_ret = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

And tweet_object, which is just another tweet:

```
tweet_object = Tweet.objects.get(id=tweet_id)
```

Comment: what is tweet_object? can you post the tweet model?

Comment: Added tweet_object and model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create Tweet object first and next you can create relations with retweets.

More about information you can find here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

It's very simply:

```
tweet_object = Tweet.objects.get(id=tweet_id) 

new_tweet = Tweet.objects.create(text = tweet_object.text, date = tweet_object.date, username = tweet_object.username, is_ret = True)  

for retweet in tweet_object.retweet.all():
    new_tweet.retweet.add(retweet)

new_tweet.save()
```

Comment: I think your `for` loop won't work this way. You can't iterate through `tweet_object.retweet`. It should be in my opinion: `tweet_object.retweet.all()`.

Comment: Maybe the `for` loop can be even abandoned: `new_tweet.retweet.add(tweet_object.retweet.all())`

Comment: There is a typo in the code example. In the `for` loop there is `tweet_objects.retweet.all()`, but it should be `tweet_object.retweet.all()`. It will throw an error because `tweet_objects` is not defined.