# Django: using ManyToMany-field as keyword during object creation causes TypeError

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

When running a Django model create call I get an error message as follows:

`TypeError: 'keywords' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

The create object is called form within a ModelViewset and looks like this:

```
the_item = Item.objects.create(url=the_photo_url, owner=the_user, keywords=the_keywords, item_type=the_item_type, title=the_title)
```

My Item model looks like this (it has a keywords field that links to a keyword table):

```
class Item(models.Model):

    ITEM_TYPES = (
        ('V', 'Vine'),
        ('Y', 'YouTube'),
        ('P', 'Photo'),         # Photo is stored by us on a CDN somewhere
        ('F', 'Flickr'),
        ('I', 'Instagram'),
        ('D', 'DeviantArt'),
        ('5', '500px'),
    )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)     
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')           
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='', unique=True)
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ITEM_TYPES)    
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, related_name='keywords')
    credits_applied = models.IntegerField(default=5000)
    credits_left = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    credits_gifted = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)               
    liked = models.IntegerField(default=0)                        
    disliked = models.IntegerField(default=0)                        
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)         
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=0)
```

The related Keyword model looks like this:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

The `the_keyords` argument to the `Item.objects.create()` is a Python list: `[1,21]`

Why is Django complaining about the Keywords parameter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When creating a model instance how to fill ManyToMany field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672337/when-creating-a-model-instance-how-to-fill-manytomany-field)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand the answer in the link you give.

Comment: Are `[1, 21]` id's of `Keyword` instances?

Comment: I find manytomany hard to understand. In the Item model there is a keywords field with a manytomany relationship to a keyword model that contains a list of string keywords. The [1,21] are indexes into the keyword table.

Comment: Understand that `keywords` is not a db column in the `Item` table. For many-to-many fields, django creates a through model with two foreign keys to the two models that are to be related by the many-to-many. In that sense, these fields are special.

Comment: Yes I kinda get the through model bit, in theory, but don't understand how I assign keyword IDs when I create the Item record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a `ManyToMany` field like that in the creation of a Model instance. For the creation of the necessary through model instances, the object must be saved first (to have a `pk`). So create the instance first, and then use the `add` method to add `Keyword` instances (you can do so with multiple at a time):

```
the_item = Item.objects.create(...)  

keywords = list(Keyword.objects.filter(id__in=[1, 21]))
the_item.keywords.add(*keywords)
```

Or, maybe a little more performant, using the through model and `bulk_create` directly will reduce the entire adding to one db hit:

```
kw_ids = [1, 21]
through_model = Item.keywords.through
through_model.bulk_create(
    [through_model(item_id=the_item.pk, keyword_id=kw_id) for kw_id in kw_ids]
)
```

Comment: That is brilliant! Thanks. I am not sure I would ever have worked that out!